# Cant texture paint when zoomed in

Tags: texture-painting

I recently switched to 2.77, and I just tried to texture paint for the first time in 2.77 and while zoomed in, I cant paint? I dont understand. I tried fiddling with the projection painting settings, but to no avail. Can anyone help me? I've had this problem all night and can't fix it

-EDIT-

I found a workaround, setting the view mode to orthographic fixes it, but i still would like to see this fixed in perspective.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer and then accept it. This will allow others to find the question/answer more easily. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If switching to orthographic view fixes it, your issue is that you have too few faces and are too close to them.

What I do is I add a simple subdivision modifier. It's frustrating that it doesn't work, but blender has trouble localizing the brush on the face when it is severely warped by perspective. Here is a post on the developer manifest.

https://developer.blender.org/T40707